# Pitot Measurement

Tags: landing

Very many years ago i used to suddenly align then flare to stall at almost exactly where I wanted to touchdown. Later, I tried to analyze why I had bounces.
Does a pitot tube measure the axial component of a crabbing aircraft's airspeed or the actual airspeed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does, but very indirectly and not in a way that is of any use. Since it's measuring dynamic ram pressure entering a little hole, any time the hole is not perpendicular to the flow, the presented opening area gets smaller and the dynamic pressure drops.

To visualize, take it to an extreme, say an angle of 45 degrees to the airstream, and the opening, looking at it from straight ahead, is an oval of much smaller area, so the dynamic pressure will be lower.

It's why the indicator reads low near stall speed, and one of the reasons you have to calibrate the speed indicator (that and to compensate for local flow velocity variations at the probe) on larger aircraft.

So when you are landing or just flying slowly with a very nose high attitude and high angle of attack, the airspeed will read several knots lower than the actual "calibrated" airspeed. Same if you are landing with a lot of side slip.

So a STOL technique in a strong crosswind could give a larger error than no crosswind and you may find your sink rate is higher, with a given speed indication, in a strong side slip than with no side slip.

Beyond keeping that in mind, I can't think of a way to actually measure that accurately enough to use, without vanes to measure the actual slip angle like test aircraft use.